# Would a Community Blog for BG.SE be useful?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange supports [Community Blogs](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/). I could see the value in having a Community Blog for Boardgames.SE, as I am sure many users find the technical rules questions a little dull. The Blog can be an escape from the dry day to day questions, and a chance to liven up the discussion in a more open format.

Some of the first things that need to be decided are the scope of the blog.

- Do we want to session reports about games we have played? I could see this as bi-weekly articles covering either new games we played for the first time and the games first impressions, new decks we tried out in a multiplayer environment, or an overview of a game and our impressions about why a particular player won.
- Do we want to review product? I have a closet full of games, but I don't suffer from the obsession that many do that are from the cult of the new. I do have some coworkers though that enjoy buying and playing newish games. I wouldn't mind offering up some reviews of board games. I could see reviewing games on a monthly basis, so that users have enough time to play 4-10 games to get a good sample size.
- In depth strategy articles or something like the Game Tech podcast that discusses game theory.

Do we have enough interest within the community to make posts, or have people read them? If I am the only one interested in this, this will fail horribly. I would think that we need at least 5-6 regular contributors, and 2-3 users who are good editors.

I am not sure the best way to track interest in the community. Upvote this post if you are interested in reading a blog? Upvote individual answers with (Product Review, Session Report, In-Depth Strategy) to indicate interest in what articles you would want to read.

Maybe a seperate thread with people interested in contributing, and another thread for people interested in consuming.

What does everyone think?